# integrating 'react-thunk': 'cannot call a class as a function'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-thunk

How fix it?

```
composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware()) // work
composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(thunk)) // don't work
```

console error message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call a class as a function
```

Code:

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension';
import thunk from 'react-thunk';

createStore(reducer, composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(thunk)));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead

```
import thunk from 'react-thunk';
```

must be

```
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
```

Comment: Holy heck, I was stuck for so long on this and could not understand why. There is an npm package called react-thunk and I must have installed that instead, which messed up all my autocomplete. I just kept looking right over "react-thunk" and seeing "redux-thunk." Anyway, you're a lifesaver, sir. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import { routerMiddleware } from 'react-router-redux';
import reducers from '../reducers/';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

const middlewares = [thunk, routerMiddleware(browserHistory), apiMiddleware];

const enhancers = compose(
  applyMiddleware(...middlewares),
);

const store = createStore(reducers, enhancers);


export default store;
```